# Postgres - searching jsonb by iterating array of objects

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in postgres as follows:

| product_id | price | f_struc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13.4 | [{"s1": {"low": 0, "high": 15, "count": 5}, "s2": {"low": 15, "high": 20, "count": 10}}] |
| 2 | 15.6 | [{"s1": {"low": 0, "high": 15, "count": 5}, "s2": {"low": 15, "high": 20, "count": 10}}] |
| 3 | 24.5 | [{"s1": {"low": 0, "high": 15, "count": 5}, "s2": {"low": 15, "high": 20, "count": 10}, {"s1": {"low": 20, "high": 25, "count": 7}} |

I want to get for each product_id, its relevant "count" value from f_struc, based on the price. if nothing found, return n/a

in this example, for product_id 1, with price 13.5, I need to get the value of "count" 5, because it's between low:0 and high:15

for product_id 2, I need to get value of "count" 10 because it's between low: 15 and high: 20

There can be N tiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_path_query_first()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.21.1.1.1) and pass the `price` as a variable into the JSONPath expression: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1D4pS-sp)

```
select product_id, description, price,
       jsonb_path_query_first(f_struc,
                              '$.**
                                ?(@.low.double() <= $price && 
                                  @.high.double() > $price)
                                .count',
                              jsonb_build_object('price',price))::bigint "count"
from test;
```

| product_id | description | price | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Basic example | 13.4 | 5 |
| 2 | Nesting is malformed | 15.6 | 10 |
| 3 | Tier bounds are strings | 24.5 | 7 |
| 4 | No tier matches price | 34.2 | *null* |
| 5 | Tiers overlap | 42 | 1 |

Comment: You might want to cast that to `::int` or `::numeric` if you wish to use the retrieved `count` as a proper number - right now it's a single-value `jsonb`. If no matching "tier" is found, this will return a `null` - which is more advised than a textual `n/a` you have to interpret yourself. If you really need that, you can by all means instead cast to `::text` and `coalesce()` to `'n/a'`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/rhiZI5af).

Comment: Agreed, but you would also want `.double()` within the JSON path https://dbfiddle.uk/kzSNMk40